# How to change constructor of a class to recieve generic list of objects of already created class and constructor? (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class OrderArticlesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public List<OrderArticleViewModel> listOfOrderArticles;
    .....
    .....
    //constructor
    public OrderArticlesAdapter(List<OrderArticleViewModel> orderArticles, ....., .....)
    {
        listOfOrderArticles = orderArticles;
        ......
    }
}
```

I want the class to be able to work not only with list of `OrderArticleViewModel` but also with list of type `Invoices` and any other type. `OrderArticleViewModel` class looks like that:

```
public class OrderArticleViewModel
{
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }

    public string LotId { get; set; }

    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    public string PriceDiscount { get; set; }

    public string ArticlePrice { get; set; }

    public string ArticleQuantity { get; set; }

    public string ArticleTotalPrice { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public string ExpireDate { get; set; }

    public string LotName { get; set; }

    public string ArticlePriceAfterDiscount
    {
        get
        {
            decimal priceDiscount;
            if (!Decimal.TryParse(PriceDiscount, out priceDiscount))
            {
                priceDiscount = 0;
            }
            decimal articlePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(ArticlePrice);
            decimal discountAmount = Math.Round(articlePrice * (priceDiscount / 100), 4);
            decimal articlePriceAfterDiscount = articlePrice - discountAmount;
            return articlePriceAfterDiscount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

`Invoices` class looks like that:

```
public class Invoices
{
    public string ArtId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Sum { get; set; }
    public string Discount { get; set; }
    public string PriceWodiscount { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

`ArticleId` , `ArticleName`, `ArticleQuantity`, `PriceDiscount`, `ArticlePrice`, `Discount`, `ArticlePriceAfterDiscount` from class `OrderArticleViewModel` correspond to properties `ArtId`, `Name`, `Quantity`, `Discount`, `Price`, `Sum` from class `Invoices`. How do I make `OrderArticlesAdapter` constructor to be able to recieve generic list of `OrderArticleViewModel` or `Invoices` or any other type without breaking the functionality of the code where I already have used instance of `OrderArticlesAdapter`?

Comment: Why not you use automapper for this. http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

Answer (score 3):

Create another constructor in which you convert the invoice list to an ArticleViewModel list:

```
public class OrderArticlesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public List<OrderArticleViewModel> listOfOrderArticles;

    public OrderArticlesAdapter(List<OrderArticleViewModel> orderArticles, ....., .....)
    {
        listOfOrderArticles = orderArticles;
    }

    public OrderArticlesAdapter(List<Invoice> invoices)
    {
        listOfOrderArticles = invoices.Select(MapToArticleVM).ToList();
    }

    private OrderArticleViewModel MapToArticleVM(Invoice invoice)
    {
        return new OrderArticleViewModel
        {
            ArticleId = invoice.ArtId,
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

Do note the resulting list will miss some properties, because `Invoice` doesn't contain `Barcode`, for example.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do what I want only with changing the parameter of the constructor `List<OrderArticleViewModel> orderArticles` with something more generic? Because if I want to pass another list which is not `OrderArticleViewModel` or `Invoice` I will have to create another constructor.

Comment: As long as there's no inheritance relation between OrderArticleViewModel or no conversions exist, you'll have to either provide an overload or convert the items prior to calling the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to write an extension method to convert an invoice to view model

```
public static class InvoicesExtensions
{
    public static OrderArticleViewModel ToOrderArticleViewModel(this Invoices i)
    {
        return new OrderArticleViewModel { ArticleId = i.ArtId, ... };
    }
}
```

... and then you can call the constructor like

```
var invoices = new List<Invoices>();

var adapter = new OrderArticlesAdapter(invoices.Select(i => i.ToOrderArticleViewModel()).ToList());
```

I would also recommend

- renaming `Invoices` to `Invoice` as it seems to represent an actual invoice not multiple invoices
- use `IEnumerable<OrderArticleViewModel>` instead of `List<OrderArticleViewModel>` for the constructor parameter as this makes the constructor more versatile